# strange closure behaviour

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, zappa

I have got this program(simplified from my actual program) where I am unable to access all variable from the method of the object passed to view, though I can access it from get. Am I missing something here?

```
all = ['hello', 'world']


require('zappajs') ->
    @get '/foo': -> 
        console.log all
        @render 'foo'

    @view foo: -> 
        console.log all
```

I get an exception, all not defined when run using coffee hello.coffee.

Comment: I seem to have figured out the reason after debugging it in node debugger. This view function is passed to coffeecup engine and it creates a new function with my view function embedded using 'new Function'. Creating a function this way doesnt create a closure. It would be great if someone can confirm :-)

Answer (score 0):

In [API references](http://zappajs.github.io/zappajs/docs/reference):

> ```
> @view path: contents
> ```
>
> Define an inline template. It’s like you had a file on disk at path inside Express’ views directory. It will have precedence over a template on disk.

Since "It’s like you had a **file** on disk at path inside Express’ views directory", so everything under `@view` is in a separate file/module, which explains why you cannot access `all`.